# Find the partial sum of $a_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n}(2\cdot 3^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, products, geometric-progressions

Is it possible to find a formula for this partial sum $S_n$?

$$S_n=2+2\times6+2\times6\times18+2\times6\times18\times54+2\times6\times18\times54\times162+\cdots+a_n$$

Here, $\displaystyle a_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n}(2\cdot 3^k)$.

Comment: @Samedov you can edit your own question, just click the [edit button](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2249659/edit) under every post.

Comment: @Frenzy Li  i dont know english.This google translate.

Comment: @Samedov, your question is fine, there's no need to edit it.  $S_n$ does represent the symmetric group but it also represents the $n$th partial sum, and since you used the [tag:sequences-and-series] tag then the context is very clear here.

Comment: Although I should point out that the reason your question is getting voted down is because it's generally expected that people posting questions show what they've attempted so far.

Comment: @Samedov You can bookmark [the basic tutorial for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5024#5024) to learn more about writing equations.

Comment: @Frenzy Li Did you know to solve the problem?

Comment: @Samedov I'm just passing by your question and edited it.  I don't know how to solve it, but I think some other people are thinking about it now.

Comment: @Frenzy Li my question was -2 votes. İ hope anyone help me.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you very much. But I do not understand. Where did he go on his last form?

Comment: @tilper Yes, I can understand how I may have missed the context (I agree it was clear, just not up to standards (as you note in your subsequent comment).  I'll delete my comment.  I'm sorry if I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, we have

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^N\prod_{k=0}^n2\times3^k$$

Notice that

$$\prod 2r^{a_k}=2^nr^{\sum a_k}$$

Thus,

$$\prod_{k=0}^n2\times3^k=2^{n+1}3^{\sum_{k=0}^nk}=2^{n+1}3^{n(n+1)/2}=2^{n+1}r^{(n+\frac12)^2-\frac14},r=\sqrt3$$

Thus,

$$S=r^{-1/4}\sum_{n=0}^N2^{n+1}r^{(n+\frac12)^2}$$

which is as far as you can simplify.

Comment: @dxiv Right.... that's horrible.

Comment: Thanks you very much. But I do not understand. Where did $-1/4$ go on your last form?

Comment: @Samedov Sorry, I fixed the last line.

Comment: Thank you very much.You are genius.100 times Thanks.

Comment: No problem! :-)

Comment: Sorry, why down voting my question?

Comment: @Samedov I haven't downvoted your question, though I presume the downvoter did so for the reasons outlined in the comments below your question.

Comment: To the downvoter of my answer, please explain your downvotes so may provide better answers.  Thank you.